# I am attempting to prefill my react hook form with data to allow me to update my task

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query, react-forms

To prefill my react hook form , I am receiving `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` in my input field.

I want to know how I can have the content of the object to prefill the form.

I know i have to make the change on the value of the form but not sure what to add in replacement as I get a Type error.
My goal is to have the prefill form with the data already in the database.
`

```
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState('');
```

```
// ----------------------------- UPDATE TASK ----------------------------------------//
    const { isLoading: isUpdatingTask, mutate: updateTask } = useMutation(
        (putId: string) => {
            return TaskService.update(
                putId,
                {
                    TaskName: putName,

                });
        },
        {
            onSuccess: (res) => {
                setPutResult(fortmatResponse(res));
            },
            onError: (err: any) => {
                setPutResult(fortmatResponse(err.response?.data || err));
            },
        },
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isUpdatingTask) setGetResult('updating...');
    }, [isUpdatingTask]);

    function putData() {
        if (selectedItems[0]) {
            try {
                updateTask(selectedItems[0].ID);
                // setVisible(true);
                

            } catch (err) {
                setPutResult(fortmatResponse(err));
            }
        }
    }
```

```
   <Modal

                    onDismiss={() => setVisible(false)} 
                    visible={visible}
                    closeAriaLabel="Close Modal">
                    <Container
                        header={
                            <Header
                                variant="h1"
                                description="To update your task..."
                            >
          Update Your Task.
                            </Header>
                        }
                    >

                        <FormField label="Task Name">

                            <Input

                                type="text"
                                value={tasks}
                                onChange={(e) => setPutInitiativeName(e.detail.value)}
                                placeholder="Init Name"
                            />    </FormField>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get it to display the data individually. using

`value={data.TaskName}`

and getting a desired output of the content of the Object in strong format.